# Higher-order polynomial in quadratic approximation

Tags: calculus, polynomials, quadratics

So I am doing an online calculus course and saw this equation:
$ Q(x+x^2+ x^3/2) $
where the lecturer mentioned that "at $x=0$, if there is a polynomial,
the quadratic approximation to a polynomial at x equals 0
is just all the terms up to the quadratic term. And higher order terms are dropped."

The resulting equation is $ x+x^2$.

What is this higher order polynomial? And how does it work that the $x^3/2$ is dropped?

Thanks beforehand!

Comment: Well, that indeed makes sense. If you have a polynomial, and you want to make a **qudratic approximation**  of it near $x=0$, you just need to drop all the terms that are larger than power two. That's the quadratic approximation.

Comment: The lecturer said "higher order *terms*".

Comment: so this only applies for quadratic terms at x = 0?